# How to chage default directory of .dlls creating after built with runtime and probing?

Tags: c#, xml, dll, .net-core, app-config

I want to move all .dlls to "lib" folder after building my application. Default program creates them in directory:

> bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2

And this is directory where I want to place my .dlls:

> bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\lib

I create script which moves my .dlls to this folder and put it in post-built event. It works correctly.

Next, I add runtime to my app.config file like I saw in many tutorials and articles on stackoverflow.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="lib"/>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But, after building and starting my program, console says:

> The application to execute does not exist:
>   *app\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\myDLL.dll*

I want to know what's wrong with my application? How can I change the directory in which program is looking for .dlls?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is the codebase element in the configuration.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/efs781xb%28v%3Dvs.71%29), If the assembly has a strong name, the codebase setting can be anywhere on the local intranet or the Internet. If the assembly is a private assembly, the codebase setting must be a path relative to the application's directory.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                      href="http://www.litwareinc.com/myAssembly.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still doesn't working. I get publiKeyToken, culture and version from Assembly.LoadFile and put them into app.config like in your answer. I was trying changing path but it doesn't help. I think that my mistake is trivial but can't find it.